# Mac equivalent to AutoHotkey's PixelSearch?

Tags: mac, keyboard, software-recommendation, mojave, mouse

I am aware of AutoHotkey alternatives such as Hammerspoon, Karabiner, and Keyboard Maestro, but do any of these have a way to search for a pixel with a specific colour on the display like how `PixelSearch` works in AutoHotkey?  Or, is there another product that I am unaware of that allows me to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to get the location of a specific color on the screen or are you trying to get the color at a specific location?

Comment: I’m trying to get (and save) the coordinates of a specific colour on the screen so I can then move the mouse to a specific positions relative to the found coordinate.